# Core Data one to one relation ship throws error

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode7

I have core data model like in below images, and need one to one relation ship. [image]

[image]

and when I am trying to add record in core data entities.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MagicalRecord.h"
#import "Child.h"
#import "Parent.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Child *child = [Child MR_createEntity];
    child.name = @"Child";

    Parent *parent = [Parent MR_createEntity];
    parent.name = @"parent";
    parent.child = child;
}
```

Xcode will throws error like below.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "child"; desired type = NSSet; given type = Child; value = <Child: 0x7feec35bc840> (entity: Child; id: 0x7feec359af30 <x-coredata:///Child/tC70A9E87-948D-4407-AE19-73F9661A29372> ; data: {
name = Child;
parent =     (
);
}).
```

Comment: I think this part of the error message: `desired type = NSSet; given type = Child;` can help you understand your problem

Comment: Actuality I have to one relation between both entities and in log Xcode show "Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship", but I have not set to many relation ship.

Comment: The child property on Parent.h is Child?

Comment: Yes, it's    @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) Child *child;

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the contents of `Parent+CoreDataProperties.h`? At least the part where `child` is declared?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Data Model editor (graph editor style), select Parent's relationship to Child and make sure that your relation looks a below:
[image]

Comment: Have you updated your data model recently? If yes, delete the app from the Simulator or the device you've been using.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems that you have defined the relationship as "to-many". This is why it is expecting an `NSSet` for relationship `child` (where indeed `children` would be more appropriate).

Assuming that you **want** a to-many relationship (i.e. a parent can have more than one child), rename the relationship to the plural as mentioned above, and make sure the model looks like this:

```
Parent <--------->> Child
```

Then the simplest way is to just set the to-one relationship:

```
// add a child to a parent
child.parent = parent
```

Obviously, if for some reason you do want a one-to-one relationship, check that the model reflects that as well.

```
Parent <----------> Child
```